# I have updated my Xcode to Version 7.3 (7D175)

Tags: xcode, swift

I have updated my Xcode to Version 7.3 (7D175) and I'm now getting a compiler crash. The project is written in Swift.

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the compiler crash?

Comment: Try cleaning ⌘-Shift-K, and if that doesn't work, go to Window > Projects, select your current project, and hit the Delete... button next to Derived Data. I get linker errors and compiler crashes nearly every day, and they get fixed with a clean. If that doesn't fix it, we will need the full stack trace to attempt to help you out.

Comment: From time to time I have fixed some compiler and linker errors just by clean -> restarting XCode -> build.

Comment: No it is not helping, I did them

Comment: I'm sorry this is happening, and it's interesting, but you are not supplying enough information to make this a useful question. It is crashing _on some line_ of code. You need to determine what line that is. The log should give you a line number, or you can just start commenting stuff out until you find it.